# Device Libraries for CEN/XFS

Tags: c#, cen-xfs

I am currently working on CEN/XFS. I have read the documentation. As far as I know, for each device (for example: Card Reader, Dispenser, Pinpad...) there is a special library (.dll) for interacting with CEN/XFS

Where can I get a library (.dll) for a specific device (for example, for a card reader)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dll is usually provided by the device manufacturer. It then gets loaded by the Xfs Manager.
If you are implementing a service provider for a specific device you have to implement this dll.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how to specify the com port address for a specific device

Comment: This should be specified in the documentation of your service provider vendor. Usually it is set automatically when installing a service provider.

Comment: For more information you can directly contact me via my github link in my profile.